# Page load doesn`t throw error even when the page hasn`t loaded and has 'Error: 500 Server Error'

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Below code is to check if page is loaded or not, it returns without any error even though page has 'Error: 500 Server Error, Application Init Error. We are unable to display the requested page.' displayed.

I haven`t tried anything other than WaitForPageLoad which have found on stackoverflow.

```
public static void WaitForPageLoad(IWebwebDriver webwebDriver, int WaitTime = 12)
{
    string pageStatus = string.Empty;
    OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebwebDriverWait wait = new OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebwebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(WaitTime));
        wait.Until(w =>
        {
        try
        {
        pageStatus = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)webDriver).ExecuteScript(@"return document.readyState").ToString();
        }
        catch (NoSuchWindowException)
        {
        webDriver.SwitchTo().Window(webDriver.WindowHandles.Last());
        }
        return (pageStatus.Equals("complete", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || pageStatus.Equals("loaded", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        });
}
```

I was expecting it to throw error when the page has errors or not loaded at all. There are also some cases where a part of the page isn`t loaded but still returns page state as 'complete'. Kindly check and let me know if this can be handled. Am even okay to check out for third party APIs like fiddler if there`re great solutions.

Comment: The page could be returning an HTTP 200 error code even though it is showing a 500 code in the HTML.

Comment: Is this a publicly accessible page? If so it would help if you provided the URL.

Comment: Matt - No it`s accessible within the network alone. Sorry

Comment: @IanKemp - Is there a way such errors can be handled in selenium or using any third parties'?

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no `document.readypageStatus`, there is [`document.readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState)  so I would recommend reconsidering your page loading completion logic.

If your application is built using [AJAX](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/) technology in addition to your function (or instead of it) you could go for [Explicit Wait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) feature like:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(12));
IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("someid")));
```

This way Selenium will wait for element with the [id attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp) of `someid` for 12 seconds and proceed as soon as it will be found. If the element will not appear within 12 seconds time frame - you will get a [WebDriverTimeoutException](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_WebDriverTimeoutException.htm)

Comment: Corrected my code, it was a mistake, is this the only option to check if the page has loaded or not? This isn`t what I was looking for.